# AVPlayer not showing after play some video

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video-streaming, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer in Collection view cell to play 5 video file on each cell while scrolling, in my case when i open my view controller with present as model view controller first time AVPlayer playing the video with streaming URL, but when i dismiss the controller and open it again AVPlayer not even showing on screen and not playing the video, i check the URL is correct and the same as the first time but on second or third time player not playing the same video. Any one please help me in this problem, i am stuck in this from past 2 days tried many thing but not found any solution. Or let me know is there any other way to play the HLS stream video in iOS.

Below is my code.

```
// adding video URL in AVPlayerItem //
self.avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaURL]];
// frame declaration of player layer //
CGRect videoRect;
videoRect = CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height);
// initilization of AVPlayer with AVPlayerItem and AVPlayerLayer  //
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.avPlayerItem];
self.avLPlayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
[_avLPlayer setFrame:videoRect];
[_avLPlayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
_avLPlayer.opacity = 1;
_avPlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
[_avPlayer setMuted:NO];
_avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
[self.viewForShowVideo.layer addSublayer:_avLPlayer];
[_avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[_avPlayer play];
// Adding a thumbnail image and Activity Indicator in view   // 
loadingIndicatorForVideo = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 177,323)];
[loadingIndicatorForVideo startAnimating];
loadingIndicatorForVideo.center = self.center;
loadingIndicatorForVideo.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
[loadingIndicatorForVideo setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[_imgForVideoThumbnil addSubview:loadingIndicatorForVideo];
[_imgForVideoThumbnil sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaDataModel.strThumbUrl]];
[_avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
// Orientation management according to video //
if ([strMediaOrientation isEqualToString:@"1"] || [strMediaOrientation isEqualToString:@"landscape"]) {
self.avLPlayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(90.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
[_avLPlayer setFrame:self.avLPlayer.bounds];
UIImage * landscapeImage = _imgForVideoThumbnil.image;
UIImage * portraitImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: landscapeImage.CGImage scale: 1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];
[_imgForVideoThumbnil setImage:portraitImage];
loadingIndicatorForVideo.center = self.center;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to track different AVPlayer events or keypaths, from where you can check that player is buffering or not ?

Comment: Yes, i tried to check player state but player is appearing in ready to play state  but not playing the video.

Comment: If its possible than give your tried code here

Comment: I added my code of initialization of AVPlayer

Comment: Where you have added this code? In cell ?

Comment: Yes, i am using collection view, and adding this code in collection view cell class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167167/discussion-between-chetan-sharma-and-nikunj-damani).